# Why does the service OnCreate get called multiple times?

Tags: delphi, service, delphi-10.4-sydney

The code below, via...

```
procedure TTimetellServiceServerMonitor.ServiceDebugLog(const AMsg: String);
const cDebugLogFile = 'd:\temp\service.log';
```

... outputs this debug info showing that we go through the OnCreate several times (I added the - -  descriptions):

```
- testsvcserverMonitor /install -
S 1802 servicecreate
S 1802 AfterInstall
- start from services app -
S 1741 servicecreate
S 1741 servicestart
S 1741 MonitorThread.Start
- stop from services app -
S 1741 servicestop
- testsvcserverMonitor /uninstall -
S 1336 servicecreate
S 1336 beforeuninstall
```

I assign a random tag value to the service in its OnCreate and you can see that these are different.

Why does this happen, is there a bug, should I prevent it and how?

(Windows 32 bit, Delphi 10.4.2. Sydney)

.pas code:

```
unit USvcServerMonitor;

interface

uses
  WinApi.Windows, WinApi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.SvcMgr, WinApi.WinSvc;

type
   TMonitorServiceThread = class(TThread)   // Worker thread
   private
      FCheckLiveEvery,
      FLastLiveCheck    : TDateTime;
   public
      procedure Execute; override;
   end;

type
  TApplicationMonitor = class(TService)
    procedure ServiceBeforeUninstall(Sender: TService);
    procedure ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
//    procedure ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);  Not necessary, WorkerThread does the work
    procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
  private
    procedure ServiceDebugLog(const AMsg: String);
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
  end;

var
  MonitorThread               : TMonitorServiceThread;
  ApplicationMonitor: TApplicationMonitor;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  ApplicationMonitor.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TApplicationMonitor.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TApplicationMonitor.ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
begin
   ServiceDebugLog('AfterInstall');
   // StartType is stAuto, but start manually after install
end;

procedure TApplicationMonitor.ServiceBeforeUninstall(Sender: TService);
begin
   ServiceDebugLog('beforeuninstall');
end;

procedure TApplicationMonitor.ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Self.Tag := 1000 + Random(1000); // For debugging
   ServiceDebugLog('servicecreate');
end;

procedure TApplicationMonitor.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
   ServiceDebugLog('servicestart');
   MonitorThread := TMonitorServiceThread.Create(true); // Suspended
   ServiceDebugLog('MonitorThread.Start');
   MonitorThread.Start;
   Started := true;
end;

procedure TApplicationMonitor.ServiceDebugLog(const AMsg: String);
// Quick-n-dirty debugging routine
const cDebugLogFile = 'd:\temp\service.log';
var t: textfile;
begin
   if not fileexists(cDebugLogFile) then
   begin
      assignfile(t,cDebugLogFile);
      Rewrite(t);
   end
   else
   begin
      assignfile(t,cDebugLogFile);
      Append(T);
   end;
   writeln(T,'S ' + Inttostr(self.Tag) + ' ' + AMsg);
   closefile(t);
end;

procedure TApplicationMonitor.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
   ServiceDebugLog('servicestop');
   MonitorThread.Terminate;
   Sleep(100);
   MonitorThread.Free;
   Sleep(100);
   Stopped := True;
end;

{ TMonitorServiceThread }

procedure TMonitorServiceThread.Execute;
begin
   inherited;
   FLastLiveCheck  := Now;
   FCheckLiveEvery := 1;
   while not Terminated do
   begin
      try
         if (FCheckLiveEvery > 0) and (Now-FLastLiveCheck > FCheckLiveEvery/1440) then
         begin
            // Do some checks
            FLastLiveCheck := Now;
         end;
         Sleep(500);
      finally
      end;
   end;
end;


end.
```

.dfm file:

```
object ApplicationMonitor: TApplicationMonitor
  Tag = 123
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = ServiceCreate
  AllowPause = False
  DisplayName = 'Test Application Monitor Service'
  AfterInstall = ServiceAfterInstall
  BeforeUninstall = ServiceBeforeUninstall
  OnStart = ServiceStart
  OnStop = ServiceStop
  Height = 250
  Width = 400
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TService* is derived from *TDataModule*, so *OnCreate* will be called when the *TService* instance is created. That obviously happens when the service is going to be started, but also when it is installed and uninstalled.

So, no, it is not a bug and you also should not prevent it.

Perhaps it is just that your expectations are wrong?

Comment: My expectations, obviously ;-) So that means that I should practically never do anything in the ServiceCreate, just initialize everything in the ServiceStart

Comment: ServiceCreate can probably be seen as an event called whenever the service's .EXE file is loaded. Such as for installing, uninstalling or starting the service. So ServiceCreate could contain things that are needed for all or many of those situations (let's say maybe creating some kind of logger?), and ServiceStart things that are needed only when the service actually is about to run.

Comment: Just keep in mind that when a `TService` is run, it runs in its own worker thread (in addition to the `TMonitorServiceThread` this code is creating). So `TApplicationMonitor.OnCreate`, `TApplicationMonitor.On(Start|Stop|Execute)`, and `TMonitorServiceThread.Execute` will run in different threads, so be careful about writing thread-safe code.